# How can cell break auto layout constraints by disappearing and how to prevent it?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, realm

This is first time I have to ask for help here - usually I am able to find or figure out an answer, but I guess there has to be a first time.

I have a weird issues.
After reloading data or after pulling the cell above boundary of table view, the image in the tableviewcell seems to break constraint and not resize properly.

This is the debugger log:

```
022-07-31 16:57:49.849599+0200 gitHubRecrutationChallengeTry2[60468:8339844] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003198b40 'id12' UIImageView:0x14d611130.width == UIImageView:0x14d611130.height   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003198b90 'id13' V:[UIImageView:0x14d611130]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x14d6109d0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003198be0 'id14' V:|-(0)-[UIImageView:0x14d611130]   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x14d6109d0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003198c30 'id15' H:|-(20)-[UIImageView:0x14d611130]   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x14d6109d0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003198d20 'id18' H:[UILabel:0x14d610b70]-(10)-|   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x14d6109d0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003198d70 'id19' H:[UIImageView:0x14d611130]-(20)-[UILabel:0x14d610b70]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000031994a0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x14d6109d0.height == 320.333   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003199450 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UITableViewCellContentView:0x14d6109d0.width == 370   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003198b40 'id12' UIImageView:0x14d611130.width == UIImageView:0x14d611130.height   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Worth mentioning, when starting the view controller there is no issues in autolayout.

Here is the ViewController itself. It grabs data from Realm - a list of saved users, displays it in UserCells. If I move to new controller and reload data it breaks, if I move the table cells up - the ones that are not visible will break.

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class SavedUsersTableViewController: UIViewController, UserDetailViewControllerDelegate {
    func userRemovedFromFavorites(userModel: UserModel) {
//        retrivedUsers.removeAll(where: {$0.id == userModel.id})
//        dataStore.removeUser(userModels: [userModel])
        getSavedUsers()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    func userAddedToFavorites() {
//        getSavedUsers()
//        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    
        
        
    
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    let localRealm = try! Realm()
    
    private lazy var dataStore = ImageDataStore()
    private lazy var loadingQueue = OperationQueue()
    private lazy var loadingOperations = [IndexPath : DataLoadOperation]()
    
    private var retrivedUsers: [UserModel] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        title = "Saved Users"
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.prefetchDataSource = self
        getSavedUsers()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    func getSavedUsers() {
        loadingQueue.cancelAllOperations()
        loadingOperations.removeAll()
        retrivedUsers = []
        let array = Array(localRealm.objects(RealmUserModel.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "userName", ascending: true))
        for realmUser in array {
            let user = UserModel(realmUserModel: realmUser)
            retrivedUsers.append(user)
        }
        dataStore = ImageDataStore(userModels: retrivedUsers)
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? UserDetailViewController {
            if let sender = sender as? UserCell {
//                destinationVC.image = sender.userAvatarImage.image
                destinationVC.delegate = self
                if let user = sender.getUserModel() {
                    destinationVC.assignUserModel(user: user)
                    
                }else {
                    fatalError("Failed at retrieving user model from the cell")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension SavedUsersTableViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let cell = cell as? UserCell else { return }
        let updateCellClosure: (UIImage?) -> () = { [unowned self] (image) in
            cell.configureCell(image)
            self.loadingOperations.removeValue(forKey: indexPath)
        }
        if let dataLoader = loadingOperations[indexPath] {
            if let image = dataLoader.image {
                cell.configureCell(image)
                loadingOperations.removeValue(forKey: indexPath)
            } else {
                dataLoader.loadingCompleteHandler = updateCellClosure
            }
        } else {
            if let dataLoader = dataStore.loadImage(at: indexPath.row) {
                dataLoader.loadingCompleteHandler = updateCellClosure
                loadingQueue.addOperation(dataLoader)
                loadingOperations[indexPath] = dataLoader
            }
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let dataLoader = loadingOperations[indexPath] {
            dataLoader.cancel()
            loadingOperations.removeValue(forKey: indexPath)
        }
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
//        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? UserCell {
//            performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToSavedUserDetails", sender: cell)
//        }
    }
}

extension SavedUsersTableViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return retrivedUsers.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SavedUserCell", for: indexPath) as! UserCell
        cell.configureCell(user: retrivedUsers[indexPath.row])
        let updateCellClosure: (UIImage?) -> () = { [unowned self] (image) in
            cell.configureCell(image)
            self.loadingOperations.removeValue(forKey: indexPath)
        }
        if let dataLoader = loadingOperations[indexPath] {
            if let image = dataLoader.image {
                cell.configureCell(image)
                loadingOperations.removeValue(forKey: indexPath)
            } else {
                dataLoader.loadingCompleteHandler = updateCellClosure
            }
        } else {
            if let dataLoader = dataStore.loadImage(at: indexPath.row) {
                dataLoader.loadingCompleteHandler = updateCellClosure
                loadingQueue.addOperation(dataLoader)
                loadingOperations[indexPath] = dataLoader
            }
        }
        return cell
    }
    
    
}

extension SavedUsersTableViewController: UITableViewDataSourcePrefetching {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, prefetchRowsAt indexPaths: [IndexPath]) {
        for indexPath in indexPaths {
            if let _ = loadingOperations[indexPath] { return }
            if let dataLoader = dataStore.loadImage(at: indexPath.row) {
                loadingQueue.addOperation(dataLoader)
                loadingOperations[indexPath] = dataLoader
            }
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cancelPrefetchingForRowsAt indexPaths: [IndexPath]) {
        for indexPath in indexPaths {
            if let dataLoader = loadingOperations[indexPath] {
                dataLoader.cancel()
                loadingOperations.removeValue(forKey: indexPath)
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Here is user cell code, if helpful:

```
//
//  UserCell.swift
//  gitHubRecrutationChallengeTry2
//
//  Created by Tomasz Kubiak on 7/23/22.
//

import UIKit

class UserCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    public static let identifier = "UserCell"
    
    @IBOutlet weak var userNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var userAvatarImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var loadingIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tipLabel: UILabel!
    
    
    private var userModel: UserModel?
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.userAvatarImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }
    
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        
    }
    func configureCell(user: UserModel){
        userModel = user
        userNameLabel.isHidden = false
        userNameLabel.text = user.userName
        tipLabel.isHidden = true
    }
    /// Configure cell image
    /// - Parameter image: UIimage to pass to the cell
    func configureCell(_ image: UIImage?) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in
            self.displayImage(image)
        }
    }
        
    /// Configure cell without username, image, or loading indicator - text to display is "Search of an user or check favorites"
    func configureCell() {
        tipLabel.text = "Search for an user or check favorites!"
        userNameLabel.isHidden = true
        tipLabel.isHidden = false
        loadingIndicator.stopAnimating()
        userAvatarImage.image = .none
    }

    
    private func displayImage(_ image: UIImage?) {
        if let _image = image {
            userAvatarImage.image = _image
            loadingIndicator.stopAnimating()
        } else {
//            where to put loading indicator?
            loadingIndicator.startAnimating()
            userAvatarImage.image = .none
        }
    }
    public func getUserModel() -> UserModel? {
        return userModel
    }
}
```

Comment: https://youtube.com/shorts/oh22CYqgrs8?feature=share <- to better describe the issue

Comment: Try reducing the priority of the image view bottom constraint to 999.

Comment: Did that on another constraint, and on the one you specified, but to no avail

Comment: If you are claiming that such a change did not change the conflict message at all, then I'm afraid I don't believe you. A constraint with a lower priority _cannot_ conflict with a constraint with a higher priority. That's just a fact.

Comment: Matt, I followed your advice, I double checked the log and I got the same result (image sized up) and the same log - the constraint with lower priority was also in the list of constraints that were causing the break. 
If you want I can record this and post it to YT if it help by any means. I would post the debug but it is too many characters for a comment.

Comment: Managed to solve it - Matt, your advice let me get rid of debugger logs when I applied additional constraint. Thanks a lot for help!